# Table index suggestion

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, database-performance

I am working with a many to many relationship, and I read some documentation that suggests not to use primary keys or indexes.

I am interested to hear what you think about my db.

It has only 2 columns, each one with bigint unsigned values (millions of rows).

Example:

```
012934567865434            10923883093280921
012984902348202            10923812122220677
012930245820556            77777883093123124
984017133446720            76567883093098765
098523467527659            09876583093890456
```

In column 1, the values repeat themselves maximum 100 times each, and if they do repeat, they are one after the other. So the pattern is:

```
value1
..value1 repeated 100 times
value2
..vlaue2 repeated 20 times
value3
value3 repeated 60 times
```

In column 2, the values do repeat sometimes, but the repetitions are not grouped one after the others.. So they could be millions of rows away.

Any suggestion on how to optimize in terms of:

- creating an index?
- using primary keys?
- reordering the columns in ascending order? If yes how often?
- Any other idea that you can think would speed it up!
  etc..

Comment: *I read some documentation that suggests not to use primary keys or indexes* Did you keep reading the documentation to find out what it suggested you do, instead?

Comment: What are you trying to speed up - reads from the table, or writes to the table? Do you need to link the table to other tables when querying it? Can the same combination of a specific value in the first column and another specific value in the second column ever exist more than once in the table? Are there other columns in this table, or only these two?

Comment: First, you always need to keep in mind that if you doesn't have CLUSTERED INDEX on your table then order of the rows in the table is absolutely unpredictable.

Second, to answer your question we realy need more information. How do you inserting and selecting data etc.

Comment: So, no indexes. You need one record from column 1... the best way to optimize; add indexes :-).

Comment: I am trying to speed up both reads and writes. I do not need to link the table to other tables. A combination of a specific value in 1st column + 2nd column CANNOT exist more than once in the table. There are only 2 columns in the table, nothing else. @mark bannister

Answer (score 1):

When you have a many-to-many relationship a usual solution is to implement three tables where `table1` (== column1 in your example) and `table2` (== column2) would contain the **unique values** in the relationship (and their primary keys if needed), and `table3` associates the two sets of keys. The relationships of `table1` and `table2` to `table3` will be one-to-many

For example:

**table1**
id1 (PK)
col1
col2
...(more columns)

**table2**
id2 (PK)
colA
colB
...(more columns)

**table3**
id1
id2
.. in table3 the pair (id1,id2) would form a unique key


In your case `table1` would contain the unique values from column1 and `table2` the same from column2, while `table3` will contain the unique pairs of values.

Answer (score 1):

Without correctness, performance does not matter. Since you say (in a comment)...

> "A combination of a specific value in 1st column + 2nd column CANNOT exist more than once in the table."

...the **correct** thing to do is to put both fields in a composite key.

To *efficiently* enforce this key however, you need an index. So, you need at least one index right there. The question is which index? That depends on the "direction" in which you wish to query the data:

- If you need to efficiently answer the question "for given `value1`, which `value2`s are connected to it", then the index should be `{value1, value2}`.
- If you need to efficiently answer the question "for given `value2`, which `value1`s are connected to it", then the index should be `{value2, value1}`.
- If you need to efficiently answer both questions, then you need *both* indexes (but beware of price you pay for secondary index in a clustered table - see "Disadvantages of clustering" in [this article](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/)).

BTW, InnoDB will generate a hidden PK in case you have not explicitly specified any PK or UNIQUE constraint. This is needed for clustering.

---

On a DBMS that supports index compression (such as Oracle), you could save space when there are many repeating values in the index's leading edge. Storage is cheap, but that's not the point - smaller data means effectively "larger" cache.

Alas, MySQL is not such a DBMS.

---

On a more philosophical note, there is no such thing as "order" unless you specify it yourself.

- In a heap-based table (MyISAM), the physical order of rows in the heap roughly follows the order of INSERTions, but is best thought of as random from the client perspective.
- A clustered table (InnoDB) is essentially a tree that orders its leafs according to clustering key (which is PK). However, query results order is not guaranteed *unless* you specify ORDER BY.
- Indexes are "ordered" in a sense, but you won't get query result in any particular order even when index is used, *unless* you specify ORDER BY.

I all 3 cases, you need ORDER BY to guarantee that the results of the query are returned in any particular order.

Answer (score 0):

Adding indexes to tables speeds up reads (particularly when joining tables), but slows down writes. Normally, read performance is likely to be a higher priority than write performance, since a record is likely to be read more often than it is written to - the exception tends to be log tables.

Apart from performance, another reason to set up an index is to prevent duplicates.

So if your table is likely to be written to frequently but read infrequently, **and** you can be certain that no duplicate combinations of columns will ever be inserted, you should probably not add any indexes to the table.

However, if your table is likely to be written to infrequently but read frequently, **or** you want the database to ensure that no duplicate combinations of columns can ever be inserted, then you should set up appropriate indexes.

Comment: ok I like your idea. What do you mean by appropriate indexes? Is there a particular type that you would suggest for my case?

Comment: It depends what you want to use them for - to prevent duplicates and speed up reads where values for both columns are specified, set up a unique index on (column1, column2). Otherwise, set up a non-unique index on whichever column is going to be most frequently accessed to return results.